# Why can't GeoTools find MutablePicoContainer#registerComponentImplementation method?

Tags: java, xsd, kml, geotools

I just started using GeoTools and am trying to generate a KML. I followed 2 main examples for my application, but I am seeing this weird error where gt-xsd-core cannot find this method **registerComponentImplementation** from the **MutablePicoContainer** class.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.picocontainer.MutablePicoContainer.registerComponentImplementation(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/picocontainer/ComponentAdapter;  at org.geotools.xs.XSConfiguration.registerBindings(XSConfiguration.java:130) ~[gt-xsd-core-16.1.jar:na]
>       at org.geotools.xml.Configuration.setupBindings(Configuration.java:528) ~[gt-xsd-core-16.1.jar:na]
>       at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.(Encoder.java:230) ~[gt-xsd-core-16.1.jar:na]
>       at org.geotools.xml.Encoder.(Encoder.java:214) ~[gt-xsd-core-16.1.jar:na]

All of my imports for Geo Tools are running the same version and I have tried versions 18.2, 18.1, 17.4, and 16.1.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geo.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xsd-kml</artifactId>
        <version>${geo.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>${geo.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geo.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

```
 import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
 import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
 import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
 import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
 import org.geotools.kml.KMLConfiguration;
 import org.geotools.xml.Encoder;

    SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(features);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new KMLConfiguration()); // Error Line
    encoder.setIndenting(true);

    try {
        encoder.encode(featureCollection, org.geotools.kml.KML.kml, System.err);
```

---

I have no compilation or startup errors. My other RESTful services are working perfectly. Mvn clean install passes successfully. I've tried adding the Pico Container (1.2) dependency to my pom.xml, but that did not work either.

I was looking at the documents for the MutablePicoContainer class and I don't see that method that GeoTools is using, even though I can see that their code is compiling with references.

PicoContainer JavaDoc:  http://picocontainer.com/javadoc/core/org/picocontainer/MutablePicoContainer.html

GeoTools XSConfiguration (18.x) Source: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/18.x/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-core/src/main/java/org/geotools/xs/XSConfiguration.java

GeoTools Example: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/xsd/kml.html

OSGEO Example: http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/2.7.5/demo/example/src/main/java/org/geotools/demo/xml/KMLExample.java

---

Please help this has cost me a lot of time debugging and I'm out of ideas on what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I can build almost [identical code](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1699232) and run it with no issues with those dependencies. If I use the `shade` plugin to create an uber jar it includes the following dependencies. As you can see picocontianer-1.2 is there.

The only thing I can think of is that it is missing from your classpath, or you have a corupt download.

```
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-data:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-kml:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-core:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:1.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.common:jar:2.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore:jar:2.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.xsd:org.eclipse.xsd:jar:2.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi:jar:2.12.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:core:jar:0.26 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including jgridshift:jgridshift:jar:1.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.sf.geographiclib:GeographicLib-Java:jar:1.44 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-main:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-api:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.vividsolutions:jts-core:jar:1.14.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-render:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-coverage:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.media:jai_imageio:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-tiff:jar:1.1.18 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-utilities:jar:1.1.18 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-geocore:jar:1.1.18 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-streams:jar:1.1.18 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.vividsolutions:jts-example:jar:1.14.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.vividsolutions:jts-io:jar:1.14.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jaitools:jt-zonalstats:jar:1.4.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.jaitools:jt-utils:jar:1.4.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.affine:jt-affine:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.algebra:jt-algebra:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandmerge:jt-bandmerge:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandselect:jt-bandselect:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.bandcombine:jt-bandcombine:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.border:jt-border:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.buffer:jt-buffer:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.crop:jt-crop:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.iterators:jt-iterators:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.lookup:jt-lookup:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.mosaic:jt-mosaic:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.nullop:jt-nullop:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.rescale:jt-rescale:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.scale:jt-scale:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.stats:jt-stats:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.translate:jt-translate:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.utilities:jt-utilities:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.warp:jt-warp:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.zonal:jt-zonal:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.binarize:jt-binarize:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.format:jt-format:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorconvert:jt-colorconvert:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.errordiffusion:jt-errordiffusion:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.orderdither:jt-orderdither:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.colorindexer:jt-colorindexer:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.imagefunction:jt-imagefunction:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.piecewise:jt-piecewise:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.classifier:jt-classifier:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.rlookup:jt-rlookup:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including it.geosolutions.jaiext.vectorbin:jt-vectorbin:jar:1.0.16 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-cql:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-swing:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.miglayout:miglayout:jar:swing:3.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.sourceforge.javacsv:javacsv:jar:2.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.7 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.geotools:gt-epsg-wkt:jar:18.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4 in the shaded jar.
```

which agrees well with the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: I can also see picocontainer on my mvn dependency tree. I am also using Spring Boot and Hibernate. Do I need to do a special configuration to tell GeoTools to use my Spring container instead of the Picocontainer?

Comment: I doubt that will work, it needs Picocontainer. Check your classpath when you are running to make sure it is visible.

Comment: Okay I will thanks, and I’ll also see if I have this shade plugin already in my pom

Comment: Shade is only necessary if you are building fat or uber jars.